# cant execute python script from php, in the client side

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, ajax

I am very new to PHP & Apache.

I am building a small webpage - which can run some python code on the server on click of a button from a client computer. To do this, I have read a few articles on the web which tell PHP is the way to do it. I also read that I wouldn't need AJAX. My understanding of PHP, AJAX and related technologies are at a beginner level.

I have an Apache server running on my RHEL 6.5 machine. 
I have PHP v5.3.3, Python v2.6.

**PHP script (script.php) :**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python pytest.py");
?>
```

- Location : /var/www/html/script.php
- Permissions : chmod 777 script.php

**Python Script (pytest.py) :**

```
import os
os.remove("/<path>/hon.txt")
```

- Location : /var/www/html/pytest.py
- Permissions : chmod 777 pytest.py

**Index HTML (index.html) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<header>
<title>Python Run</title></header>
<body>

<p>
<b><font size="10" color="red"><div align="center">Run Python Jobs</div></font></b>
</p>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Script1</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>
                <form action="script.php" method="get">
                        <input type="submit" value="Run Py Script">
                </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Other things/tests done :**

- The Python script works standalone, its a simple python script to delete a file.
- The PHP script also works standalone on the machine running the Apache server.
- When I try the button click from HTML, the PHP script does not seem to work.
- I have checked the log messages from

  ```
  cd /var/log/
  tail messages -f

  May  6 18:22:01 machine abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pytest.py'
  ```
- I was not sure if this could be because of permissions, so I did a

  ```
  chmod 777 -R /var/www
  ```

  Even then I had the same problems
- I was not sure where things were going wrong, so I made 2 more changes to the PHP script (script.php) :

  ```
  <?php
  echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /<path>/pytest.py");
  echo shell_exec("ls");
  ?>
  ```

  Over here - the second line works from browser, the first one does not. Which means my python portion is not getting executed.

I read somewhere if this is a problem because my Apache server is not run with root privileges. Being new - I don't know how to check that.

If any more information is needed - I can provide details in successive edits.

Comment: Could it be because the argument to your shell_exec() does not execute it from the root directory? Try     echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python pytest.py");

Comment: `I am very new to PHP` - Run! Run away! Run like your life depends on it!

Comment: @That1Guy : Run To or From PHP ? :)

Comment: You use PHP to run Python? I think I'm about to break down and cry. :-( In .htaccess you can tell Python to execute .py files as CGI scripts. Then add the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` (or whatever version) to the top of the file.

Comment: `May  6 18:22:01 machine abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in 'pytest.py'` you need to debug your python script, handle the exception to see what the error is.

Comment: @cmorrissey - thats a good tip - let me put an exception check in python.

Comment: @EricE - I have tried what you have told already

Comment: @Kay - can you point me to an example ?

Comment: @Suddev Try what Exceen had mentioned in his answer. Also by any chance does you python script require sudo access to run?

Comment: @EricE - Tried Exceen's suggestion it did not work. And python script works fine as is on the server machine without sudo. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing the full path to your file. In your case you just say `'pytest.py'`, so replace it with the full path.

Doing so, this would result in something like this:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /home/username/scripts/pytest.py");
?>
```

(Also, you missed one `/` in front of `usr/bin/python`)

Comment: Thanks for this - I just made this correction ... and my python scripts are in /var/www/html , i even tried an another location and it does not work

Comment: If your scripts are in /var/www/html, did you try `"/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/pytest.py"` already? And what's the error message when you try this? (or is it still the same?)

Comment: I tried "/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/pytest.py" - does NOT work - complains saying pytest.py cannot be found. BUT, when I try "/usr/bin/python pytest.py" - it works. I am losing my head :(

Comment: your comments were helpful I have something working. I have moved the python scripts to /var/www/html .. and now I am able to get it to work.

Comment: It will be nice to have it working on any python script in any folder